# why not correct when using global resource in Try with resource

Tags: java, java-7

I am using try with resources, and I found if I use the out statement, then I get something wrong

Correct one,

```
try (FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter(mergedFile, true);) {
 }
```

Incorrect one

```
FileWriter fstream = null;
try (fstream = new FileWriter(mergedFile, true);) {
}
```

I am wondering why I cannot use the second one? The scope of with resources is different?

Comment: Resources in a `try-with-resources` block only exist inside it and are closed automatically when the block is left.

Comment: Try catch block limits the scope

Comment: Because variable is out of scope to try with resources that needs to be closed at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's correct, since a resource declared with *try with resources* is *closed* at the end of the block, it is not available outside the scope of that block.

Having a resource persist in the scope *after* the block wouldn't make sense, since it's already closed and you most probably can't make use of it (some sort of "reset" nonwithstanding).

You can also re-use the same variable name in multiple blocks, since it only exists in the block's scope.

So you could follow with another `try (FileWriter fstream = ...)` after your first block.

Answer (score 0):

There are two reasons ,
1. Resource has to be final. outside declared variable may be changed at any point during the execution of the try-with-resources block. This would break its cleanup and will make it inconsistant.

2. Resource scope must be try block associate with it.

Following are the exact words from Java 7 Specification Document,

> A ResourceSpecification declares one or more local variables with
>   initializer expressions to act as resources for the try statement.
>
> A resource declared in a ResourceSpecification is implicitly declared
>   final (§4.12.4) if it is not explicitly declared final.

Also from 6.3 of Specification

> The scope of a variable declared in the ResourceSpecification of a
>   try-with-resources statement (§14.20.3) is from the declaration
>   rightward over the remainder of the ResourceSpecification and the
>   entire try block associated with the try-with-resources statement.